# Excluding files beginning with certain expression when cleaning Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to exclude cleaning certain zip files when cleaning jenkins workspace. I have a zip file named my_file_timestamp.zip. timestamp part is generic, thus I would like to exclude zip files beginning with my_file. I tried

```
my_file*
my_file**
my_file.*
```

but all files are still deleted during cleaning workspace step :(

Comment: Are the zip files in the top level workspace directory or are they in a subdirectory?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot or code of your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

The files might be in a subdirectory

```
**/my_file*
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, the files are still deleted :/